# html5 postMessage not working

Tags: javascript, html, cross-domain, postmessage

My window.addEventListener's function is not getting fired even when I repeatedly send the domain messages via postMessage. It's seems like it isn't receiving any response at all. Here is the code:

```
var myUrl = 'http://localhost:8085';
var newPopup = window.open( myUrl, '_blank', '' );

// Create listener
window.addEventListener('message',function(event) {

  if (event.origin !== 'http://localhost:8085') return;
    console.log('received response:  ',event.data);

},false);

// Setup messenging
setInterval(function(){
    var message = 'Hello!  The time is: ' + (new Date().getTime());
    console.log('blog.local:  sending message:  ' + message);
    newPopup.postMessage(message,'http://localhost:8085');  
},2000);
```

Why doesn't the listener ever pickup the messages?

Answer (score 0):

You are registering the handler on the wrong window. Try

```
newPopup.addEventListener('message',function(event) {
    ...
```

Comment: Shouldn't the eventlistener be registered to the target window, not the message sender (the popup)?

Comment: In your code the message sender is your current window and the target of the `postMessage` is your popup window. So the listener should most likely be registered on the popup window.

Comment: Doesn't newPopup.postMessage() mean the message is being posted FROM newPopup?

Comment: No, it's posted TO `newPopup`, check the [MDN documentation of `postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/window.postmessage).